# Object in list is not iterable

Tags: python, oop, iterable

I'm creating a chess game in Python. Below I have a method to display the board. The problem is, it only displays the first square.piece.piece_type. I have tested the contents of the list and there are 64 (as it is supposed to be). How can I return all object vars?

```
    def board_display(self):
    counter = 0
    while counter <= len(self.squares):
        for square in self.squares:
            return square.piece.piece_type
    counter += 1
```

I have tried using counter as index but then it returns `TypeError: 'square' object is not iterable`

EDIT(solved):

The return (apparently it end the whole function and not just the loop) was the main issue. I placed the separate list parts in a new list and returned that new list.

```
    def board_display(self):
    output = []

    for square in self.squares:
        output.append(square.piece.piece_type)
    return output
```

Comment: What is `self.squares` here?. Also **Make sure you indent your code correctly.**

Comment: Do you want to return a list, or…?

Comment: self.squares is a list

Comment: full traceback please and/or [mcve]. that doesn't seem to match the code. there's no place where `square` is iterated upon here.

Comment: I want to return a variable of a subclass called piece, obviously square does contain a piece object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem described in the question is caused by the fact that as soon as you reach a `return` you leave the `board_display` function. It is not executed after that and thus you only return the first `square.piece.piece_type`. `counter` **never** becomes 1 or 2 etc.

So you may want to return the list of squares and not every single square.